# Frameset Alternative HTML5 to change certain div content

Tags: html, frameset

I couple of years ago I paid a simple HTML pages with a side bar and a 'main frame'. The Main Frame would auto refresh into another page using: ***meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL='/target.html'"***

Now I want to update it to HTML5. I still want the sidebar to stay 24/7 in place and the main frame content to refresh or change into another page/content (being it videos, paragraphs of text or images).

I found out that framesets don't work anymore. Cause I had it set up to: Sidebar = a frame and Main Frame = a frame and just refresh the source of the main frame into the next page of content.

Any alternatives?

Comment: You'll have to learn a new technique to replace the frames.  It's not a matter of a simple code change.  Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8528475

Comment: Yes but for that method I have to click a new link. I want it to swap content automatically after a certain time.

Answer (score 1):

The kind of solution you are looking for, was described here by the author himself.
He needed a sidebar fixed, while changing the content fo the main screen.
He used before the framesets, then he found the solution described, in order to be able do not use them, but HTML5.
[HTML5 alternative for frames with 1 fixed (menu) column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46214183/html5-alternative-for-frames-with-1-fixed-menu-column)

Answer (score -2):

The modern way to do this would be with AJAX.  See the answer to this question:

[How to fire AJAX request Periodically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052543/how-to-fire-ajax-request-periodically)